# Objective-C: Type casting object to integer_t

Tags: objective-c

`integer_t` is a typedef of `int32_t` as defined [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/integer_t?language=objc), and after some checking, `integer_t` has a size of 4 bytes, and so does `int` ([intValue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1414988-intvalue?language=objc)) as per mentioned is this [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-6223/chp-typeopexpr-2/index.html). My question is, is casting like this produce valid result?

```
integer_t value = 100;
id anObject = @(value);
integer_t aValue = [anObject intValue];
```

Is `aValue` always equal to `value`? Will this cause any issue in the long run? Should I do `long value = [anObject longValue]` instead? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a comment - the title to this post is a bit misleading. Nowhere do you cast an object to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short and specific answer - YES those values are equal since `integer_t` and `int` both (according to you - here's the catch) have the same size AND the same signedness. If one was e.g. some type of unsigned int then it would not work. Neither would it work if one was e.g. 8 bytes (long) and the other 4 (int).

The long and general answer is - it depends. Yes, here you think it is equal but there are always funny cases you need to watch out for. I already mentioned the size and signedness but the real trip can be over the system architecture. So you might assume they are the same and then one day you compile for 64b arch and all breaks down as `int` there has 8 bytes length and `integer_t` still is 4 e.g. You could also run into endianness troubles. Thus if you get a bunch of `int`s from a mainframe they could be stored `BADC` where A, B, C and D are the 4 bytes of the int.

As you can see, it is easy to scare anybody working with these, and in practice that is why there are things such as `NSInteger` - Objective-C's attempt to protect you from these. But don't be scared, these are toothless monsters, unless you work at a low level, and then your work will be to work with them. Doesn't that sound poetic.

Back to the code - don't worry too much about these. If you work in Objective-C, maybe try to use the `NSInteger` and `NSUInteger` types for now. If you store these and need to load it again later then you need to think about the possibility that you store it from a 32b arch and restore it on a 64b arch and work around that somehow.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear explanation. Regarding the `NSInteger`, If my source (where I don't have the authority to change it) is an `uint32_t`, I assume there's no point in casting it to `NSInteger` anymore?

Comment: *Suggestion* If in your source it is defined as ```uint32_t``` then keep it that way and don't cast.